# How to capture login name and restrict the view to only records submitted by the user

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo, and Spring MVC.

I have Set up Spring Security to use a MySQL database and auth using the standard schema, table users, table authority.

What I have is a webapp to take orders from our sales people in the field. Simply they just fill in the form and submit it to the database.

The ROO generated MVC pages are fine to start, but I need to make some changes and I'm not sure exactly how to do it. I'm just getting my feet wet learning java.

What I need is for our sales order form to capture the username, and the submitted record would be tagged with their username, and then filter the view so that the sales person can only see the records that they themselves have submitted.

Also I would like to implement a stylus signature capture at the bottom of the form. I tried to figure out how to use http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#howto but I'm getting lost on where to put the code. I assume in src\main\views\salesorders\create.jspx 
I understand this part is off-topic to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a table in your database that holds the order forms.  An important part of this table will be each row will need to contain a way to map back to the user that submitted it.  This will most likely be easiest to implement with a column that is a foreign key to the user table.

When it comes time to fetch for forms for a specific user, you will need to query the order forms table and use a `WHERE` clause that restricts the rows to just the current user.

As for your second question, it will likely be more worthwhile for you to ask in another question on stackoverflow, as it doesn't really pertain to the original question at all.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a table that will contain the orders. For the time being I had created another table which is populated with the Salesperson names, and then when submitting the order they would select their name from a drop down list. To avoid potential abuse I'd like to just capture their name based on their login name instead of selecting from a list. Do you know what function that would be? Here's a line from my create.jspx as it is now. 
`code` <field:select field="salesTech" id="c_com_aaceglass_domain_SalesOrder_salesTech" itemValue="id" items="${salestechnicians} (truncated)

Comment: That is a pretty specific question.  It may be in your best interest to dig deeper into Spring security and how it provides user information to your backend server's MVC controller.

Comment: Yup this is where it gets a bit tricky. I have authorities, ROLE_SALES, ROLE_CSR. The CSR should view all records. The SALES only their own records. Perhaps one way to do it is to have specific finders only viewable by their role. But then that wouldn't stop them from viewing other's records. so in my SalesOrder.java I have `@NotNull @ManyToOne private SalesTechnician salesTech;` then to grab the username `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();` goes in there somewhere but I have no idea where. :\